# How to update docker version in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, auto-update, amazon-ecs

I intend to run some apps stateful in only 1 container instance in ECS, no config autoscaling. My purpose when running this container instance in ECS is find an easy way to update docker version by support of ECS. 
But seen like to update docker version in ECS, I have to launch a new instance with latest Amazon ECS-optimized AMI, then move data from a old one to new one, lastly remove the old one, it such complicated, so my question: is there any way to update docker version in AWS ECS without downtime?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bring down the containers that are running in order to update Docker.